# HttpErrorResponse while downloading a file from a server

Tags: angular, http, http-headers

I spent lot a lot of time to find a solution using 'file-saver' angular module to handle a file download from my apache server.

In the front-end, the method used to download is :

```
 public download(document: any): void {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/octet-stream, */*');
    this.api.download(document.id, headers).subscribe((response) => {
      this._save(response);
    });
  }
```

The 'api' do the following :

```
  public download(id: number, headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      Constants._ICE_API_ROOT + 'Download/' + id,
      { headers }
    );
 }
```

When i run the Angular App and check the console, get HttpErrorResponse :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://crmapi.wrk/Download/2", ok: false, …}

SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

And it seems to be correct as the content returned by the server is the content of the file i want to download...

At the backend side, the PHP code is simple :

```
$path = $document->folder . $document->name;
if (array_key_exists("HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS", $_SERVER)) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'] . "," . $document->type);
} else {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: " . $document->type);
}
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $document->name);
header("Content-Type: " . $document->type);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Length:". $document->size);

readfile($path);
exit();
```

So my questions :

- Are headers sent from client correct ?
- Are headers sent from server too ?
- Why my file is not handled by the Angular module ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Please use `{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}` in RequestOptions while sending the request. Import `ResponseContentType` from `@angular/http`.

And hopefully through `this._save()` you are using `filesaver's` `saveAs()`. Although it shouldn't be a problem but try using with `this._save(response.blob())`

---

For `HttpClient`, I don't think there is any `ResponseContentType`, I believe what will work for you will be: `{responseType: 'blob'}` or `{responseType: 'text'}` try either.

You don't have to set this as a header in the request, `responseType` is part of `RequestOptions` as pointed out in a comment below.. Have a look at this: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

So, basically your request will look something like:

```
this.http.get<any>(url, { headers: yourHeaders, responseType: 'blob'});
```

Comment: Thx... But, i'm using Angular6, and don't know how to send responseType header, just have to append headers ? And yes, i'm using saveAs() in the private _save() method...

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert: When you use `this.http` in your service, what is `http` there? what is the import statement for that?

Comment: The http is the HttpClient object coming from @angular/common/http

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert: See if my updated answer helps you?

Comment: It is not a header; there is no need to send response type as a header. It goes in the requestoptions. [Take a look at the overloads for get for an example](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

Comment: @user184994: I am sorry, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I will edit my answer..

Comment: So, according your answers, change the way i get the file... This way :
  public download(id: number, headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
      responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(
      Constants._ICE_API_ROOT + 'Download/' + id,
      { headers: headers, ...options }
    );
  }
But, first, TS failed to compile with an incompatibility of type on options

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert: Okay, I have not actually worked with `HttpClient`, I just gave a probable solution. I referred few links, can you try: `this.http.get("url", { headers: "headers", responseType: "blob" as "blob"});`, I have removed the return type `<any>`. I referred this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18672

Comment: Will try as soon as possible... Thx for all... Will tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

Finally, and according to @AshishRanjan solutions, i update my code this way :

component code :

```
public download(document: any): void {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Accept', document.type);
    this.api.download(document.id, headers).subscribe((response) => {
      this._save(response, document);
    });
  }


  private _save(rawDocument: Blob, document: any): void {
    saveAs(rawDocument, document.name);
  }
```

API :

```
public download(id: number, headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
      Constants._ICE_API_ROOT + 'Download/' + id,
      { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob' }
    );
  }
```